# How to create custom themes while using actionbar appcompat v7 library?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

Google's developer site says "If you've created a custom theme, be sure it uses one of the Theme.AppCompat themes as its parent."
Can anyone show me an exampleb because i could not make the example on their site work for me.

Answer (score 0):

is very easy if you use this great tool http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/. in Style compatibility select "AppCompact".